# CSS ::after - content property display unicode icon (2192) with the same styling on every browser

Tags: css, unicode

I'm building a website and I want to display an icon behind a menu-item if that contains a submenu. The sub-menu is not displayed by default, but on click (done with Javascript). I added the arrow like this:

```
.menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    content: "\2192";
    width: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: serif;
}
```

I noticed that on Firefox it looks like this: 
[image: Unicode 2192 on Firefox]

but on Safari, Edge and other browsers it looks like this: 
[image: Unicode 2192 on Safari, Edge etc.]

I tried changing the font-family to e.g. serif, in an attempt to display the icon on every browser the same, but that didn't work. Firefox always displays the correct icon, while Safari, Edge etc. display different icons. If I change the font, Safari and Edge also change the styling of the icon, while Firefox remains and displays the same one always.

How do I get every browser to display the same icon, just like Firefox does?

If I visit other websites, like this [Unicode Search website](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html) or this [Unicode Character entities](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/entities/arrow.htm), it does display in every browser the same icon, just like I want.

So how do I display the version for the icon like it is displayed in Firefox and on the websites in every browser?

Comment: @Martin thanks!! That does it. If you submit it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: That's great. It's worth checking the [Browser Inspector](https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549) to see what's going on, when these things happen `:-)`

Comment: Well, I did use the Browser Inspector but only to try new things and not to look what the settings were on the websites ;-) Next time I'll make sure to do that first.

Comment: Do you also know why Firefox was not affected by the font-family property, but always displayed the correct one? Or is that just how Firefox 'is'?

Comment: I don't know, I was turning off and on different font families on the Inspector in Firefox on the Unicode website and that was making a difference so .... no clues there, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [the unicode website](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html) the font family used is actually `sans-serif`; not `serif`.

Using `serif` on that website changes the arrow that is displayed (ie making it not the one you want).

Therefore, it appears `font-family: serif;` does not display these unicode characters correctly; so you should substitute `sans-serif` instead:

```
.menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    content: "\2192";
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```